# How does dma_alloc_coherent ensure that memory allocated is not cached by processor?

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, x86, dma

As per Linux Documentation/DMA-API.txt `dma_alloc_coherent` allocates a region of `<size>` bytes of consistent memory.

I tried to go to the implementation of `dma_alloc_coherent` for x86. This function will call `ops->alloc`, which for intel platforms is `intel_alloc_coherent`.

**`intel_alloc_coherent` uses `alloc_pages`** to allocate virtual addresses:

```
page = alloc_pages(flags, order);
```

Then **how in this implementation it is made sure that the memory allocated is not cached by processor in its L1 or higher level cache?**

Comment: IIRC x86 is DMA cache coherent. https://lwn.net/Articles/2265/

Comment: Hmm .. you mean to say DMA controller is also participating in cache coherence done in CPU. I/O is also coherent as the CPUs are. A DMA write to RAM shall invalidate all the stale copies in CPU caches. I am still searching for more related details in Intel architecture.

Comment: It looks like MESI protocol for coherence supports IO coherence/DMA controller also. Intel nehalam supports MESIF

Comment: I am searching for the answer for the same question. Have you figured it out?  I just wonder how coherency between CPU/controller/linux is assured after memory allocation.

Comment: Hi Luke, as I understood the memory allocated is mapped to the physical area of device which is coherent. It means that the hardware is coherent, modification of any address in coherent area will make cache invalidations automatically(driven by hardware). So if DMA area gets modified then CPU caches are invalidated by cache snooping. This is programmed in the hardware.

Comment: Thanks for replying on this old thread. The explanation makes sense, otherwise I don't see how coherency is maintained without any further explicit call to flush/invalidate the cache unless linux is actively monitoring and flush all allocated dma coherent buffers to do so.

Comment: for arch with incoherent caches, it can overwrite dma_map_ops to setup the allocated page as non-cacheable to support coherent buffer.